# Repeating/Resetting an observable

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I am using rxjs to create a "channel nummber" selector for a remote control on a smart tv. The idea being that as you are entering the numbers you would see them on the screen and after you have finished entering the numbers, the user would would actually be taken to that channel.

I use two observables to achieve this:

1. A "progress" stream that listens to all number input and emits the concatenated number string out as the numbers are inputed via the scan operator.
2. A "completed" stream that, after n milliseconds of no number having being entered, would emit the final numeric string as completed. EG: 1-2-3 -> "123".

Here is the code that I use to try and solve this:

channelNumber:

```
module.exports = function (numberKeys, source, scheduler) {
    return function (completedDelay) {
        var toNumericString = function (name) {
                return numberKeys.indexOf(name).toString();
            },
            concat = function (current, numeric) {
                return current.length === 3 ? current : current + numeric;
            },
            live = createPress(source, scheduler)(numberKeys)
                .map(toNumericString)
                .scan(concat, '')
                .distinctUntilChanged(),

            completed = live.flatMapLatest(function (value) {
                return Rx.Observable.timer(completedDelay, scheduler).map(value);
            }),
            progress = live.takeUntil(completed).repeat();

        return {
            progress: progress,
            completed: completed
        };
    };
};
```

createPress:

```
module.exports = function (source, scheduler) {
    return function (keyName, throttle) {
        return source
            .filter(H.isKeyDownOf(keyName))
            .map(H.toKeyName);
    };
};
```

createSource:

```
module.exports = function (provider) {
    var createStream = function (event) {
        var filter = function (e) {
                return provider.hasCode(e.keyCode);
            },
            map = function (e) {
                return {
                    type: event,
                    name: provider.getName(e.keyCode),
                    code: e.keyCode
                };
            };
        return Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, event)
            .filter(filter)
            .map(map);
    };

    return Rx.Observable.merge(createStream('keyup'), createStream('keydown'));
};
```

Interestingly the above code, under test conditions (mocking source and scheduler using Rx.TestScheduler) works as expected. But in production, when the scheduler is not passed at all and source is the result of createPress (above), the progress stream only ever emits until complete, and then never again. It's as if the repeat is completely ignored or redundant. I have no idea why.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Window](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/window.html). In this case, I would suggest [WindowWithTime](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/windowwithtime.md). You can also do more interesting things like use [Window(windowBoundaries)](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/window.md) and then pass the source with [Debounce](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html) as boundary.

```
source
  .windowWithTime(1500)
  .flatMap(ob => ob.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, ""))
```

Also, since our windows are closed observables, we can use [Reduce](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/reduce.md) to accumulate the values from the window and concat our number.

---

Now, this variant will close after 1,5 second. Rather, we would want to wait x seconds after the last keypress. Naïve we could do `source.window(source.debounce(1000))` but now we subscribe to our source twice, that's something we want to avoid for two reasons. First we do not know is subscribing has any side effects, second we do not know the order subscriptions will receive events. That last thing isn't a problem since we use debounce that already adds a delay after the last keypress, but still something to consider.

The solution is to [publish](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/publish.md) our source. In order to keep the publish inside the sequence, we wrap it into [observable.create](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/create.md).

```
Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
    var ob = source.publish();
    return new Rx.CompositeDisposable(
      ob.window(ob.debounce(1000))
        .subscribe(observer),
      ob.connect());
}).flatMap(ob => ob.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, ""))
```

Edit: Or use [`publish`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/publish.md) like this:

```
source.publish(ob => ob.window(ob.debounce(1000)))
    .flatMap(ob => ob.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, ""))
```

Comment: Actually instead of `Observable.create` it seems i can use [`let`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/let.md), will need to dive into that and update this answer once i get some time.

Comment: Thank your dorus for the informative and detailed answer! Let me get my head around this and play a little bit :) If this solves the use case I have, I will of course accept the answer....but I wonder, could you provide insight into why what I'm doing originally does not work, especially given that it works in test conditions? I assume its some sort of async/concurrency issue that the test scheduler resolves in its own way?

Comment: For example, my case seems to be analogous to the accepted answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33567530/accumulating-and-resetting-values-in-a-stream/33576462#33576462 .... My thinking is that my issue here has something to do with the fact that "progress" is takenUntil "completed" when in fact "completed" is itself derived from "live"...I had naively assumed this wouldn't be an issue (given immutability of rxjs operator methods)

Comment: @rollcona I found your code a little difficult to read, but I've tried a little harder this time and i think it is indeed because of the line `live.takeUntil(completed).repeat()`. My guess would be that the problem is that `completed` is not recreated, instead it is reused. Could be a race condition too, something i tried to guard against in my code with `let`. Also you could try to use `completed = live.debounce(completedDelay)`.

Comment: Anyway, hard to say what's really going on unless i try to run it myself and hack around a little, if you still need more, you could try to post a live demo somewhere like jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com etc.

Comment: Thanks Dorus, in the end, let was exactly what I needed!

Comment: @rollcona Oops, i just figured out i shouldnt be using `let` at all. Instead there is an overload on `publish` that does what we want. Bit late but at least i corrected it now :)