# Rectangle clip not scaling with canvas when zoom

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

[**Here is how I created a Rectangular clip**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44498440/1927832)  to drop images in specific portion and now extending it a bit. Added zoom functionality to it.

Below is how I created a clip.

```
function clipByName(ctx) {
    this.setCoords();
    var clipRect = findByClipName(this.clipName);
    var scaleXTo1 = (canvasScale/ this.scaleX);
    var scaleYTo1 = (canvasScale / this.scaleY);
    ctx.save();

    var ctxLeft = -(this.width / 2) + clipRect.strokeWidth;
    var ctxTop = -(this.height / 2) + clipRect.strokeWidth;
    var ctxWidth = clipRect.width - clipRect.strokeWidth;
    var ctxHeight = clipRect.height - clipRect.strokeWidth;

    ctx.translate(ctxLeft, ctxTop);
    ctx.scale(scaleXTo1, scaleYTo1);
    ctx.rotate(degToRad(this.angle * -1));

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(
        clipRect.left - this.oCoords.tl.x,
        clipRect.top - this.oCoords.tl.y,
        clipRect.width,
        clipRect.height
    );
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
}
```

However this clip is not getting zoomed with Canvas. This is how it looks like after zooming it.

[image]

Full code and demo is here : https://jsfiddle.net/yxuoav39/2/

It should look like below even after zoom. Adding a [small video clip](https://i.gyazo.com/81b5bd8f32575f1bcecccc7453ec45d1.mp4) to demonstrate the issue.

[image]

Played around scaleX and scaleY and not succeed. Any pointers would be much appreciated to trace the bug.

Answer (score 1):

The clip is set to the transform that is current when you create the path for the clip. Any changes after the clip path has been created do not effect the path and thus the clip.

Eg

```
ctx.save()
ctx.scale(2,2);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(10,10,20,20); // scale makes the clip 20,20,40,40
// no transforms from here on will change the above rect
ctx.scale(0.5,0.5);  // << this does not change the above rect
ctx.clip();   //<< clip is at the scale of when rect was called
```

Comment: Any thing to avoid this ?

Comment: @SureshAtta no. I always found it a good thing. Its the same with all path objects, after you define it with a call like `ctx.moveTo`, `ctx.arc`, `ctx.lineTo`, etc they can not be changed.