# How can I manage to move object between various layers?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs, layer

I need to move object between layers, actually I have a main working area (say shape of square) and inside this working area I have a similar shape (bleed shape) same of the outer one but smaller in size, something like this :

https://jsfiddle.net/p0hszz22/24/  [see circle, square, rectangle shapes]

```
//@ add main square
function addSquare() {
  clearThisCanvas();
  var square = new fabric.Rect({});
  canvas.add(square);
  addSquare1(); //call bleedline square
}

//@ add bleedline square
function addSquare1() {
  var square = new fabric.Rect({});
  canvas.add(square);
  centreOnCanvas(square);
}
```

So I got two objects on canvas, now my requirement is when I add any image and move that image(or any object) inside the working area the dotted line(bleed shape) should always be on above of my image, so that it shows the user hint that images or anything outside the bleed region will be ignored (present case : does not happened at all )

What I have tried :

1. I tried to change the order of these two shapes,and when I did the bleed shape hides itself when main shape(outer one) is selected.
2. I thought of making these shapes into a group but again no success.

How can I achieve this? all I need is to show the user as soon anything  crosses the bleed line, it will not be considered.
Any link to study or keywords that I can again look for or any suggestion or any example will be helpful.

Thanks

PS: sorry for code in fiddle actually it was just to setup things quickly.

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44498440/7132835
It might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an overlay image for the bleeding shape, maybe that fit your needs. 
That image will always be on top of the other objects inside the canvas

```
canvas.setOverlayImage('http://fabricjs.com/assets/jail_cell_bars.png',
     canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
        opacity: 0.5,
        width : 400, // your width
        height : 400, // your height
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  yes overlayImage helped me  but not for Image but for the shape (bleed shape) then I am able to take image back of bleed shape. Is there any link to know more on 'setOverlayImage' what configurations we can do with it. Thanks

Comment: Though I have achieved this but this overlay causes to generate extra shape when I do canvas.toSVG()? any reason for this?

Comment: here check this example :
1. created base shape
2. created bleed shape
3. setOverlayImage for shape

now when I clear the canvas, it still shows the circle on canvas and can be easily exported, even canvas.getObjects() gives empty array

https://jsfiddle.net/0LrxLyLj/3/

Comment: Hi, you are using setOverlayImage wrong. PLease check this: https://jsfiddle.net/josefano09/0LrxLyLj/4/ and read my comments

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yes that's for image and I am dding the shape, is it what I am doing wrong? but I can have many shapes (circle, triangle, polygons, rectangle etc. ) and of different sizes and that bleed shape I have to put on the top. can there be some other work around for shapes instead of images ? Thanks

Comment: You can use canvas.sendToBack(myObject) to send your recently added object to the back so that your bleed object always stays on top. Additionally, use canvas.set('preserveObjectStacking', true) to preserve the layering order.

Comment: yes, it helps out but isn't it will hide it back (as image object going to be in smaller size then the bleed shape ) and it won't be get selected or resized or moved if I do 'canvas.sendToBack(myObject)'.Thanks